# problema creating a trigger in oracle to update other table

Tags: oracle11g, triggers

i'm creating a trigger to update other table to audit.
My main table that is being audited is "employed" and the audit table is "salary_history". Every a update is made in emplyed table the salary_history must be updated.
I'm working with this trigger in oracle 11g:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER salary_auditing
AFTER UPDATE ON employed
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
BEGIN

  INSERT INTO SALARY_HISTORY(ID, EMPLOYED_ID, OLD_SALARY, NEW_SALARY, DATE_MODIFIED) VALUES (SELECT MAX(ID)+1 FROM SALARY_HISTORY, ID, :OLD.salary, :NEW.salary, SYSDATE)

END salary_auditing
```

The problema is that when i run this trigger i receive this error:

```
Relatório de erros -
ORA-04082: referências NEW ou OLD não permitidas nos gatilhos de nível de tabela
04082. 00000 -  "NEW or OLD references not allowed in table level triggers"
*Cause:    The trigger is accessing "new" or "old" values in a table trigger.
*Action:   Remove any new or old references.
```

In english it means that the NEW or OLD values is not allowed at table nivel.

what modifications i should do?

Answer (score 0):

- Oracle has row-level and statement-level triggers.  Only row-level triggers have access to the `:new` and `:old` pseudorecords.  Your trigger is currently defined as a statement-level trigger.  You need to add `FOR EACH ROW` to make it a row-level trigger.
- Getting the `max(id)+1` in an `insert` statement is a really really bad idea.  Unless you have a single user application, that will cause multiple sessions to get the same value and lead to duplicate key errors.  Create a sequence and use that sequence.
- Saying `REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD` is pointless.  Unless you are intending to provide different aliases for the `:new` and `:old` pseudo-records, omit that.  And you should almost never use different aliases.

I would expect that you want

```
create sequence seq_salary_history_id
  start with <<value larger than what is currently in the table>>;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER salary_auditing
  AFTER UPDATE ON employed
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO SALARY_HISTORY(ID, 
                             EMPLOYED_ID, 
                             OLD_SALARY, 
                             NEW_SALARY, 
                             DATE_MODIFIED) 
    VALUES (seq_salary_history_id.nextval, 
            :new.ID, 
            :OLD.salary, 
            :NEW.salary, 
            SYSDATE);
END salary_auditing;
```

If you only want the trigger to fire when you are updating the `salary` column (since that's the only thing you're tracking history on), add an `OF salary` to your trigger declaration

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER salary_auditing
  AFTER UPDATE OF salary ON employed
  FOR EACH ROW
```